# How to judge permutation-similarity from eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutations, similar-matrices, permutation-matrices

I need to judge whether two $N\times N$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are permutation-similar or not; if we have $A_{ij}=B_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)}$ where $\sigma(i)$ denote a permutation, we say $A\sim B$. Here $\sim$ denotes the permutation-similarity.

For simplicity, let us assume $A$ has eigenvalues which are not degenerated.
Apparently, the eigenvalues of $A$ and those of $B$ should be the same if $A$~$B$.

Let us consider a set of matrices $\{\tilde{A}^m |m=1,2...N\}$, where $\tilde{A}^m$ are $A$ but skipping $m$-th column and $m$-th row. Thus the dimension of $\tilde{A}^m$ is $(N-1)\times(N-1)$. We can calculate $(N-1)$ eigenvalues of $\tilde{A}^m$.
The eigenvalues should be the same as the eigenvalues of $\tilde{B}^{m'}$ if $A\sim B$.
Combine all eigenvalues of $\{\tilde{A}^m\}$ together, we have the total number of $N \times (N-1)$ eigenvalues. Adding $N$ eigenvalues of $A$, we have total of $N^2$ eigenvalues. All these eigenvalues of $A$ and of $B$ are the same if $A\sim B$.

The degree of freedom of the total number of eigenvalues $N^2$ are the same as the degree of freedom of the matrix elements $N^2$. Thus it should be impossible to make continuous changing of matrix elements of $A$ with keeping the $N^2$ eigenvalues.
I think that this implies $A$~$B$ is judged by these $N^2$ eigenvalues.

Am I correct? I guess I have something wrong.
My purpose is characterizing matrices for finding (or screening) $B$ for given $A$,  among a large set of candidates $B$.

Comment: Are we given that $A$ is a symmetric matrix?

Comment: The fact that there are $N^2$ such numbers does not, on its own, guarantee that these numbers determine $A$ up to permutation similarity

Comment: It is notable that, in the absence of further information (such as $A$ and $B$ being permutation matrices), these values do **not** determine $A$ up to permutation similarity in the $2 \times 2$ case. For example, the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&-1\\-1&0}
$$
are not permutation similar, but all of these eigenvalues are the same

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.
I have to compare two inner-product matrix $A_{ij}={\bf r}_i \cdot {\bf r_j}$. (This is to compare atom-centered clusters in crystals).

Comment: You're welcome. Also, a correction to a comment: for my third comment, I meant to say "such as $A$ and $B$ being **adjacency** matrices"